# Getting the modification time of a file on a FTP server

Tags: ruby, ftp, last-modified

I need to get the modification time of a group of files on a server. I know how to get this on a local computer, but `File.mtime` doesn't work via FTP. How would I convert this code to work on a server?

```
files_sorted_by_time = Dir['*'].select { |f| 
  ((Time.now - File.mtime(f)).to_i / 604800) < 7 
}
```

Comment: `File.mtime` works on *files*. How are you going to use that via FTP?

Comment: I am making a script that downloads flv files that have been uploaded in the past week, converts them to mp4, and re uploads them.

Comment: When you download the file, it will be created the moment you download it. Some FTP clients go through the trouble of fetching the modification time from the server and applying it to the downloaded file, but this is has to be done deliberately if you're doing the download inside of Ruby. FTP has almost *zero* standards for date and time formatting, writing a full-featured FTP client is truly frustrating and difficult. If you can use SCP instead, your life would be immeasurably better.

Comment: @tadman sounds good to me. I just need code to get the job done. how would I go about this?

Comment: Have you tried [Net::FTP#mtime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/ftp/rdoc/Net/FTP.html#method-i-mtime)?

Comment: Yes, I have, but I failed to get the syntax correct for some reason. how would I switch mtime from the code above into Net::FTP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want [Net::FTP#mtime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/ftp/rdoc/Net/FTP.html#method-i-mtime).

Example from documentation:

```
Net::FTP.open('ftp.netlab.co.jp') do |ftp|
  ftp.login
  files = ftp.chdir('pub/lang/ruby/contrib')
  files = ftp.list('n*')
  ftp.getbinaryfile('nif.rb-0.91.gz', 'nif.gz', 1024)
  ftp.mtime('file.pdf')
end
```

You can use `#mtime` with `#nlst` to filter through the list of remote files.

```
Net::FTP.open('ftp.netlab.co.jp') do |ftp|
  ftp.login
  ftp.nlst do |file|
    if ftp.mtime(file) # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Is there a way I could get the mtime of the files on the server and only download the ones in the past week?

Comment: I just tried the code you gave me and it gave a huge error. I posted the code and error here http://pastebin.com/Da97cJg4

Comment: I deleted the line ftp.login but I still got an error on the line with Net::FTP.open(bla, bla, bla) do |ftp|

Comment: Alright why don't I teach you some of my favorite debugging techniques [in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34707/q-getting-the-modification-time-of-a-file-on-a-ftp-server).

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough reputation

Comment: there is some sort of glitch in stackoverflow, I have enough rep to chat, but it says It won't let me

Comment: I found out why chat didn't work. It was opened before I had enough reputation. And also, I got rid of my errors. I'm still having problems though.